# How to use dwarf to map instructions in object file to source code line

Tags: object-files, dwarf

I'm new to dwarf and used some tools like `addr2line`, `objectdump`. However, the problem I'm facing is that I want to get all the instructions in object files/static libraries mapping to its source code lines. The tricky part is that there is no address in object file since every function starts from `0x00`. So `addr2line` doesn't work(or maybe I didn't use it correctly).

Do you know any suggestions or existing tools, instead of parsing dwarf info by myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `objdump -d -S some-object.o`?

Comment: Thx, it outputs human readable result. Since I need program to understand this mapping, I have developed a tool by myself to go over the dwarf info.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I write a tool to iterate the `.debug_line` info to get the mapping by myself. BTW, I find the function sequence in `.debug_line` is not the same as it in `.debug_info` section. The `.debug_line` sequence is the same as the function binaries in object file, but `.debug_info`'s sequence is followed by another rule.